# Web driver IO's browser console function: getLogs not working when message contains Json Object

Tags: javascript, json, browser, console, wdio

I am trying to use WDIO's getLogs('browser') to capture debug info from a JS application. The debug info is in JSON format. In manual testing, i can see all the data in JSON from console. But when i utomated it in WDIO. The message returned from getLogs for that entry doesn't contain the JSON data, it only shows it as Object. The message is like 'JSapplication.js line 123 Object', so it is useless. Does anyone know how to get the data in JSON? By the way the JS application is from a third party, not editable.

I was able to grab the message, but it is not what I wanted

Comment: What about JSON.stringify(yourJsonObject,null,2) if you want indent 2 for example or skip additional parameters.

Comment: Object is a sub string in message. I didn't get the real json object.

Comment: Then there is no way probably when you get Object as string, JSON is lost - you cannot get it again - last chance is before automatic conversion by .toString() method call somewhere...

Comment: True, I saw the json content in message last week, so i started automation. But when my automation code is ready, it shows Object only. I don't know if it was caused by chrome version was updated from 98 to 99. I can't test on the old version since it is not my personal computer. I believe the log went through chrome console -> chrome driver -> selenium -> wdio. Not sure which step got changed. Anyway it is out of my control. Just hoping it could be fixed.

Comment: Are there any ways in wdio other than browser.getLogs to retrieve the browser console logs?